# PHP image don't upload to server

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having a problem in getting a image uploading to the server (first I convert it to .png and resize it):

In functions.php

```
function imageUploadedResize($source, $target,$nWidth, $nHeight)
{

   $sourceImg = Imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($source));
   if ($sourceImg === false)
   {
      return false;
   }
   $width = imagesx($sourceImg);
   $height = imagesy($sourceImg);
   $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
   imagecopyresized($targetImg, $sourceImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth,$nHeight,$width, $height);
   imagedestroy($sourceImg);
   imagepng($targetImg, $target);
   imagedestroy($targetImg);
}
```

In uploadtoServer.php

```
if(isset($_POST["fileToUpload"]))
    {
    $target_dir = "img/data/";
    $fn = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $newFileName = mysqli_insert_id($link).".png";
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imageUploadedResize($fn, $target_dir.$newFileName, 45,60);
    }
```

If I change $fn to a static image like "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/54789364/JPG-logo-highres.jpg" it works so I guess I am having a problem in $fn. Any thoughts what can it be?

Comment: A good reason why you shouldn't suppress error messages by prefixing the functions with `@`

Comment: Remove the `@` character from your code. We cannot help you if you don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Have you enabled [PHP error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)?  And if so, what errors are you getting?

Comment: PHP dont retrieve any errors. Sorry forgot to say that. I am using visual studio code so it haves syntax errors reporting.

Comment: @Exprove, did you actually try it without the `@` or did you just remove that from your question?

Comment: I tried it. No errors nor warnings.

Comment: `isset($_POST["fileToUpload"])` I assume should reference `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: All your file path declarations should be **absolute** not *relative* (they may work as relative but it's a likely contender for cause of failure if your relative file structure and location is not exactly correct.).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Hmm if i place $_FILES instead of $_POST it doesn't go inside the if. I can't acessing to $_FILES, if I print_r($_POST) with values it assigns them but if I print_r($_FILES) there is nothing there with file uploaded or not... Any Ideas? Server configuration?

Comment: Can you post your HTML form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1:**

### Form input

As Johnathan mentioned, you're checking `isset($_POST["fileToUpload"])` when a file upload form will supply the value in the `$_FILES` array. So you need to change your reference from `$_POST` to `$_FILES` otherwise it will always return false.

Edit: As your comment states you are getting 100% false, you should use a more specific qualifier such as `if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == 0)` .

Your HTML form submitting the data needs to be `enctype="multipart/form-data"` otherwise your server will not collect anything file shaped from your form. HTML forms also need to be set in the `POST` method.

**Part 2**

### File storage:

Your references to file system storage for the image, such as `$target_dir = "img/data/";` are relative, so that means that the value of `$target_dir` needs to be the child of the file that is calling that script block.

It would probably help you a lot to use **Absolute** file system references, typically (but not exclusively) using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/data"`;
This example will store data in the `www.your-web-site.com/img/data` location.

**Part 3**

### Displaying the image.

You have a header setting content type to `image/png` but you do not actually output the image, instead saving it to the file reference mentioned above. If you want to *output* the image to the browser, you need to skip saving it so:

```
imagepng($targetImg, NULL);
```

This will then output the image in `$targetImg` straight out to the browser. At the moment you appear to be *saving* it but not *displaying* it, despite setting the image header which means that any output to browser is expected to be an image content.

***Some*** systems have a restriction on freshly uploaded data and prevent that data being handled too freely, to get around this it is advisable to use [`move_upladed_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to save the file to a "proper" destination and then access it to output to the browser.

### Further Notes:

- You should be checking `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']` before acting on the file, as this will tell you if a file is present. using `isset` is a bad (very ambiguous) idea on this as the array can still be set, even if the file has not been uploaded.
- You should use [PHP error logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). You should not use error supression `@`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did everything but completely forgot enctype="multipart/form-data"...

Comment: I had almost forgotten it too, but the clue was your comment that there was no `$_FILES` data on the receiving page. Glad you got it fixed :)